# Why is adding top/bottom/right padding on textarea moving the scrollbar and handle in as well?

Tags: html, css, textarea, padding

I would like to apply matching paddings to my text inputs and textareas, but when I apply a padding to a textarea, it moves the little handle for adjusting the text area in as well, and it looks stupid, at least in Firefox. Is there a way to fix this, or am I just being OCD? I personally think it looks horrible.

Thank you.

Comment: Shadow DOM would be nice right now...

Comment: I see the problem in FF18, http://jsfiddle.net/2bkMH/1/

Comment: Appears to be an old (unresolved) bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to remove the resize handle, just add `resize: none` to your CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/2bkMH/2/ for a demo.